# Where are the gaps of our knowledge of physics preventing us from building a tractor beam?

Tags: internal-consistency, technology, space

So we could capture FTL ships in transit and reverse-engineer them.

Comment: I do not think this question can be answered. We don't have a **credible** explanation how FTL works, so we can't say how another technology we don't have would counter it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are the gaps of our knowledge of physics preventing us from building a tractor beam so we could capture FTL ships in transit and reverse-engineer them?  **All of them, I think.**

Sadly, this scenario is so far into the realm of science fiction that there is no hope of passing a reality check:

- There is no known mechanism for a tractor beam to operate on.  None of our theories in physics permit it.  One could theoretically pull something clever off with gravity, but there is no known way to cause gravity to do anything but what it usually does.  You need lots of mass, and you get a very uniform effect in all directions.
- We have no known mechanism for FTL travel.  At the moment, all known theories of physics prohibit FTL.  Accordingly, we have no clue how to snag one mid transit, because we have no physics model describing FTL.

So basically, we don't know a single bit about the process of using tractor beams to capture FTL ships.  In fact, our current theories suggest it cannot be done, so the first step would be a new discovery that permits development of new theories which *do* have FTL and tractor beam mechanisms.

My recommended discovery: a FTL enabled ship crashlands on Earth due to a navigation error.  The FTL drive is shot, but its tractor beam is intact.  Even better, any anti-tamper capabilities the aliens put on their tractor beams to protect the technology is damaged in the crash.  Our scientists go about rewriting the physics book using what we learn from the crashed spaceship, then build a bigger tractor beam to capture the buggers and steal their FTL drives.